# CakePHP call really old css file. How to refresh

Tags: css, cakephp-2.1

I have my default.ctp file

```
...
<?php echo $this->Html->css('style.css'); ?>
...
<style type="text/css">
      // other css rules
</style>
...
```

If I merge the "other css rules" at the end of style.css this rules will never be used. Why? 
I don't know how to proceed. I've deleted manually cakephp's cache, clear firefox's cache, and even try to append `?v=0.1` when I called css file, but nothing change.

Comment: Look at your browser's (Chrome/Firefox/Safari) network/file inspector to see which file is getting loaded. Cake is not "calling" any CSS. It's just the browser loading a file from the server. Figure out if that's your actual problem first.

Comment: Is the the **.css** suffix neccessary? I thought the HTML `css()` helper method appended **.css** to filenames automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer from nonslone is good, but this will disable the advantage of using cache, it will load new css file everytime loading page. Instead of using `time()` function, try to use `filemtime()` function, this function will outputting last modified datetime for the file, so the browser will only load the css if css file is modified or (absolutely) if chace is empty.

```
<?php echo $this->Html->css('style.css?'.filemtime('style.css')); ?>
```

Comment: great solution! however for cake 3 need to folder `css/` prefix - `filemtime('css/style.css')`

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the updated css file is really uploaded to the server?

What happens when you load the css file in the browser? domainname.com/css/style.css

Try the following to force the browser to disable the cache

`<?php echo $this->Html->css('style.css?'.time()); ?>`